# How to add assets bundled only in integration tests in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have set of integration tests that includes image text recognition and user interaction. For tests, I am using static images instead of camera input. I have included those images as `assets` to be able to access those in the test via `rootBundle`. However now, those will be included in production build of the app.

How to add assets for tests only?

```
flutter:
  assets: #I need those to be bundled for tests but not for production build
    - ./test/resources/
    - ./test/resources/barcodes/
```

Comment: A question, did you can call rootBundle.loadString(key) during the test?
I'm stuck in reading assets during the widget test!!!